# How to include pagination parameters in a cakephp 3.x route

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want my orders index to be sorted by id descending when I open the start page `/`. Here are the routes I have tried so far:

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Orders', 'action' => 'index', 'sort' => 'id', 'direction' => 'desc']);

$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Orders', 'action' => 'index', '?' => ['sort' => 'id', 'direction' => 'desc']]);

$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Orders', 'action' => 'index', 'pass' => ['sort' => 'id', 'direction' => 'desc']]);
```

None of them work (i.e. the sorting parameters are ignored), even though the request object looks fine when I use the second option with the `?`.

How do I have to setup the route?

Edit:

```
/?sort=id&direction=desc
```

This url display what I want to see at `/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `RedirectRoute` which will issue a HTTP 301 redirect:

```php
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Orders', 'action' => 'index', '?' => ['sort' => 'id', 'direction' => 'desc']], ['routeClass' => 'RedirectRoute']);
```

Alternatively you can set [pagination parameters](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html) in the controller and add ordering there. Note, that this ordering will persist even if you click on another column to sort by that and the generated SQL will have something like: `ORDER BY Orders.created ASC, Orders.id DESC`.

If this behavior is not desired, you can avoid that by not setting default ordering when `sort` and `direction` query params exist.

Something like this:

```php
class OrdersController extends AppController
{

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $query = $this->getRequest()->getQueryParams();

        if (empty($query['sort']) || empty($query['direction'])) {
            $this->paginate['order'] = ['Orders.id' => 'desc'];
        }

        $orders = $this->paginate($this->Orders);

        $this->set(compact('orders'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the pagination parameters solution, thank you. However I will leave the question open. It was possible to define pagination parameters in routes in cakephp 2.x and I would like to understand why it does not work in 3.x any longer.

Comment: As far as I can tell, from a quick glance at the `Route` class, it seems that the `Request` object is not being updated from the `Route`. I might be missing something though.

I suppose you could make a hacky custom route class and update it.